# Is there a way to print all values of 'i' in for loop inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

With following for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
    },10);
}
```

I'm trying to print all values of 'i' inside setTimeout();
With above code i know before reaching to console.log() all 'i's are 10 as setTimeout is async.

So I used below code

```
for(var i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(console.log(i),10000);
}
```

I did got output 1-9 but not after 10sec.
How can i get values of 'i' from 1-9 with out storing in a different variable outside setTimeout.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: `function req(i) {
    if (i >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(i);
            req(--i);
        }, 1000);
    }
}`

Comment: this value of "i" had to come via for loop only and setTimeout had to be inside that for loop. Is this possible like that or not.